# Rust nested lazy iteration and the interaction with mutable closures

Tags: rust

Nested iteration combined with side-effects don't seem to work very well with Rust iterators.  Here is an example:

```rust
fn main(){
  let v1=vec![1];
  let v2=vec![3];
  let mut v3=vec![];
  v1.iter().map(|x|{
    v2.iter().map(|y|{
      v3.push(*y);
    })
  });
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
4 |     let mut v3=vec![];
  |         ------ variable defined here
5 |     v1.iter().map(|x|{
  |                     - inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
6 | /     v2.iter().map(|y|{
7 | |       v3.push(*y);
  | |       -- variable captured here
8 | |     })
  | |______^ returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
```

I assume the problem has something to do with the laziness of iterators and a conflict between the two closures.  What is causing the error?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: Hint: what if `v1` contains two elements, and I collect its iterator? You will end up with overlapping mutable references to `v3`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't think that is the problem, since I can change `v3.push(*y);` to `v3.clear()` and the error remains.

Comment: It still needs to capture a reference to `v3`. To clarify: the references are inside the captured values of the second closure.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Sorry, I misread your original message.  Yes, this makes sense.  Is there anything that can be done?  This seems like a substantial limitation of iterators.

Comment: @EdMcMan: It is a limitation of iterators combined with mutable closures. You could argue that limitation is a good thing because having uncontrolled mutable closures out there could become a mess. What can be done? At first thought, one: do not use iterators, use loops instead; two: do not use mutable closures, return the required values and collect where needed.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't really make sense to use iterators anyway. You are creating a nested iterator yielding lots of `()` values, and you are running it only for the side effects. If all you care about are the side effects, use loops instead.

Comment: I think it's a fun challenge to always say "How would I do that via iterators". But as people here correctly point out, it's actually _more_ idiomatic to use a for loop if there's lots of side-effects involved, especially if they're non-trivial.